# Boofcv - java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.ddogleg.struct.Factory

Tags: boofcv

I'm trying to detect the rectangles inside the images. I decide to try Boofcv  [Example detect black polygon](http://%20https://github.com/lessthanoptimal/BoofCV/blob/v0.29/examples/src/main/java/boofcv/examples/features/ExampleDetectBlackPolygon.java) These are maven dependency for this tutorial.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.35</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-geo</artifactId>
        <version>0.36.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-feature</artifactId>
        <version>0.36.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.36.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-swing</artifactId>
        <version>0.36.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-recognition</artifactId>
        <version>0.36.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-io</artifactId>
        <version>0.36.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-ip</artifactId>
        <version>0.36.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>visualize</artifactId>
        <version>0.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ddogleg</groupId>
        <artifactId>ddogleg</artifactId>
        <version>0.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.georegression</groupId>
        <artifactId>georegression</artifactId>
        <version>0.22</version>
    </dependency>
```

However, I get error like this.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.ddogleg.struct.FastQueue.(Ljava/lang/Class;Z)V
> at boofcv.struct.PackedSetsPoint2D_I32.(PackedSetsPoint2D_I32.java:43)
> at boofcv.struct.PackedSetsPoint2D_I32.(PackedSetsPoint2D_I32.java:65)
> at boofcv.alg.filter.binary.LinearExternalContours.(LinearExternalContours.java:66)
> at boofcv.abst.filter.binary.BinaryContourFinderLinearExternal.(BinaryContourFinderLinearExternal.java:49)
> at boofcv.factory.filter.binary.FactoryBinaryContourFinder.linearExternal(FactoryBinaryContourFinder.java:49)
> at boofcv.factory.shape.FactoryShapeDetector.polygonContour(FactoryShapeDetector.java:115)
> at boofcv.factory.shape.FactoryShapeDetector.polygon(FactoryShapeDetector.java:100)
> at com.application.ExampleDetectBlackPolygon.main(ExampleDetectBlackPolygon.java:36)

I really dont know which version of dependency I should be using. It should be working but I cannot solve this org.ddogleg.struct.FastQueue error.

Answer (score 0):

If someone might have an issue with the maven dependencies,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-core</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-geo</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-feature</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-all</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-swing</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-recognition</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-io</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>boofcv-ip</artifactId>
        <version>0.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.boofcv</groupId>
        <artifactId>visualize</artifactId>
        <version>0.26</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ddogleg</groupId>
        <artifactId>ddogleg</artifactId>
        <version>0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.georegression</groupId>
        <artifactId>georegression</artifactId>
        <version>0.17</version>
    </dependency>
```

These are the versions I have used. It's working now!